# Unable to use library files to my project on android

Tags: android, eclipse, graph

Right now i am trying to create a graph in android,after searching from google and i got some solution as, to import the chart library files into my project.Likewise i downloaded that library file, and imported successfully into my project,but here my problem is after importing of that file my project showing error as

**console**

```
[2012-08-16 12:32:42 - Graph_test] /Graph_test/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.
[2012-08-16 12:32:44 - Graph_test] /Graph_test/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.
```

Can anyone tell me how to over come this issue?

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

- Right click on the project and go to "Properties"
- Select "Java Build Path" on the left
- Open "Source" tab
- Click "Add Folder..."
- Check "gen" folder and "Res" folder and click Ok and Ok again
- Again right click on the project and in the "Andriod Tools" click on "Fix Project Properties"

Comment: if i follow your suggestions,then my console showing like this--- [2012-08-16 13:00:39 - GraphTest] W/ResourceType( 5748): Bad XML block: header size 87 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2012-08-16 13:00:39 - GraphTest] C:\Users\Prabu\workspace\GraphTest\res\menu\activity_main.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/menu_settings').

Comment: This is the problem regarding the resource you are using in your project.The Resource are not found.Try to repeat the above criteria for Res folder too.I am Updating the my Answer too.

Comment: The problem about use of library is Solved by doing the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

If the library is another project on your space (or even jar file) then you can right click on your project and select properties. Then go to Android (where you choose version) and at the bottom you will find "is library" section. You can add it there by clicking on add